# Unable to update/add/delete user to group in Ranger

Tags: rest, api, hive, apache-ranger

1. We have a requirement to add/update/delete a user to a group in ranger through rest API. I see that there are rest API available using the userId but not through userName.  Is there any way we can do this ??.
   2.Also while creating a user the id that is given in JSON request is not taken, instead ranger creates its own id for the user and gives it back as a response. Is there a way to force ranger the id that I provide. But even this id is not seen anywhere in the ranger UI.

Comment: Ranger generates IDs for services, policies, and users too. It doesn't honor explicitly provided IDs.

Comment: @shriyog thank u but is there any way we can update users with their names rather than ids.